# How to copy value of textarea into clipboard and remove textarea in the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a function that deletes a textarea after user copy value of this textarea into clipboard:

```
$("textarea").bind('copy', function() {  
             this.remove();
});
```

The problem is - when I press CTRL+C script deletes textarea before it allows copy value to clipboard.

How to copy value to clipboard and then delete textarea?

Comment: You could set a short delay before removing the text box?

Comment: Try this `$("textarea").bind('oncopy', function() { });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could force the remove event to happen in the next event loop using setTimeout:

```
$("textarea").on('copy', function() {  
    var textarea = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        textarea.remove();    
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mpntr5yd/)

(Note I replaced your bind with on, as recommended from jQuery 1.7 onwards, and I referenced `$(this)` instead of `this` to ensure the jQuery event was used. You were probably using [ChildNode.remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode.remove) unknowingly)